# java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am working on project GWT 2.7 and google app engine server. when i run my application local google app engine server then i am getting below exception due to this i am not able to run my application.

```
I have set -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=900 in eclipse.ini file.
```

how to solve below error :-

```
2017-12-02 13:09:23.172:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
2017-12-02 13:10:30.904:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=64552ms
2017-12-02 13:10:30.904:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@bef2d72{/,file:///C:/NEON%20Projects/27-11-2017/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp21/Slick%20Erp/,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\NEON Projects\27-11-2017\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp21\Slick Erp}
java.lang.Exception: Timeout scanning annotations
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations(AnnotationConfiguration.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1363)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:346)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:284)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:274)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:368)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:214)
2017-12-02 13:10:30.948:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@72a7c7e0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
2017-12-02 13:10:30.952:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @78529ms
```

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This used to happen to me a lot on my old computer because it was constantly low on resources. Starting an app server would then cause it to swap the memory to disk a lot. Also my HDD was slow. These two would make the scanning slow and eventually time out. Make sure nothing is eating up your resources needlessly (e.g. Chrome) and increase the timeout if you must. No other ideas... The new computer had more RAM and an SSD, and the problem went away.

Comment: You can send -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=900 to the Maven run goal if you are using that.

Try

appengine:run -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait=900